# Xcode8 Provisioning profile expired on 2017-10-24 after changed the date of system

Tags: xcode8, provisioning-profile

As titled, I changed the date of my computer system to  2038/1/1
for something else, and then I resume to 2016, however the profile in my Xcode 8 is expired on 2017/10/24 that is the system date is still 2038/1/1 as the photo shows below.
The question is how can I solve it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you quit Xcode / restarted the Mac since the date was changed back? That will likely fix it. Xcode obviously is out of sync with the system date/time and you'll need to get it back in sync before the profile expiration check will work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to apple member center, check if that specific provision profile shows as valid or expired. I assume it will be valid, if so, delete that provision profile from your mac and re-download it from the member center. Inc case the provision profile is expired also in member center, then you will need to generate a new one...